# How to get a UAE visa as a 16 year old minor?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, uae, minors

I am  16 years old and my visit visa to Dubai was rejected by Indian govt as i am a minor.
Is t any way to get it?

Comment: The Dubai visa was rejected by the Indian government? Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Yeah, probably in a bid to stop underage labor exploitation @JoErNanO

Comment: sebin, can you expand on how or why the visa was rejected. Was the visa application refused by the Dubai consulate/embassy?

Answer (score 3):

As a minor, you can only travel to Dubai as part of a school trip, or with your parents or legal guardian.

Comment: Can you add a reference to a source to back this up?

Comment: According to [this](http://qatarairways.visasolution.info/FrmEligibleCountries.aspx), you need to be at least 25 if you're traveling alone, though elsewhere I've seen a requirement as high as 40 (!) for certain nationalities (not Indian) and another source says it's normally 21 for men and 25 for women. Whichever you believe, it's well over 16. While there are a lot of things I'd like to say about these policies, I'll just go with "if they don't want you, you really don't want them."

Answer (score 2):

Visas for Dubai are issued by the UAE government. The Indian government can neither issue nor refuse visas for any country except India itself. Try again, applying to the right consulate this time. A visa must always be applied for with the government of the country you want to *go to* (or its representative), not the one you *come from*.

Comment: You are right, but they can define eligibility rules for their citizens and other restrictions (as there are specifically for Indian citizens and the UAE).

Comment: No -- the rules for whom the United Arab Emirates will grant a visa to visit the United Arab Emirates are set entirely by the government of the United Arab Emirates, and the government of India has no say in whom the United Arab Emirates will allow to enter the territory of the United Arab Emirates.

Comment: If, as you apparently claim, the govenment of India has been infiltrated by former commissars from East Germany or whatever, and has therefore taken to deny its population the _**fundamental human right**_ of leaving one's home country and traveling any second country that will allow them to enter, then that STILL does not give the government of India any say over which visas another sovereign government -- the United Arab Emirates -- issue for their own territory.

Comment: ECR is required only for work visas; Dubai consulate has no relation to this, they can & do issue visa without knowing that. ECR comes into play when person tries to depart from India, and is going to Dubai or 17 other countries, on a work visa.

Comment: While this is correct, it's not really an answer. There is a distinct likelihood that the OP simply mistyped.

Comment: ...and please stop arguing about the travel restrictions of ex-communist regimes, which is in no way relevant to the question.

Comment: Since ECR is only required for work visas, and the OP appears to be saying he wanted a visit visa, this all seems off-topic. It would obviously help if he could clarify who he applied to, what he applied for, and precisely what the rejection notice said.